# Get TelemetryClient in DbContext provided by DbContextPool

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, connection-pooling, azure-application-insights, ef-core-2.2

When adding a `DbContext` to your service container via `AddDbContextPool`, it appears that you can only use a constructor with a single argument of `DbContextOptions<YourDbContextImplementation>`.

To get a `TelemetryClient` in .NET Core 3+, it is NOT recommended (aka deprecated) to instantiate `TelemetryClient` with 'new'.

Given these two constraints, how can one get a `TelemetryClient` when you cannot get one via Constructor DI?

A potential use case would be a Metric to track how many `DbContext` are created.

(I am currently using EF Core 2.4 due to pending updates to handle the breaking client-side evaluation changes in 3)

Comment: Usually, what is between "<" and ">" is a type parameter, not an instance.  The signature of the DbContextOptions Constructor looks like DbContextOptions(IReadOnlyDictionary<Type,IDbContextOptionsExtension>) according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptions.-ctor?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbContextOptions__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IReadOnlyDictionary_System_Type_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Infrastructure_IDbContextOptionsExtension__) page.  Would you care to "correct" that part of your question?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD Updated to specify Implementation rather than Instance

Comment: What is the definition of "YourDbContextImplementation"?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD just using the most basic implementation of `public class YourDbContextImplementation : DbContext { public YourDbContextImplementation(DbContextOptions<YourDbContextImplemenation> options) : base(options) { } }`